# Overcoming the 1024 character limit with setx

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to set environment variables using the [`setx`](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) command, such as follows

> setx PATH "f:\common tools\git\bin;f:\common
>   tools\python\app;f:\common tools\python\app\scripts;f:\common
>   tools\ruby\bin;f:\masm32\bin;F:\Borland\BCC55\Bin;%PATH%"

However, I get the following error if the value is more then 1024 characters long:

> WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.
>
> SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

But some of the paths in the end are not saved in variable, I guess due to character limit as the error suggests.

Comment: There's a list of alternative ways to edit the `%PATH%` at http://superuser.com/questions/297947

Comment: Look into [Rapid Environment Editor](https://www.rapidee.com/en/about) which allows you to edit all envirnoment variables graphically (you can also save a backup also).

Comment: Is anyone else bother by this claiming success when it clearly does not do what was requested? Is it not troubling that this doesn't fail while leaving the path exactly how it was?

Comment: Does this still truncate on windows 10?

Comment: Yes, it does on Windows 10

Comment: it still does on windows 1909

Comment: For windows I can recommend a module to set variables through registry in Python. Also has CLI app: https://github.com/beliaev-maksim/py_setenv this has good control on user/system level and does not have limit in length as setx

Comment: setx is the worst as it destroys your applications which depend on path, so use the powershell one-liner described [in a comment by @mark-c below](https://superuser.com/a/410179/547698) like so: `powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path',\"%newPath%;$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path','Machine'))\",'Machine');"`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your best bet is to edit the registry directly.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` and edit the `Path` value (then reboot to activate the new value).

Note however that while you can enter a very long path, (up to the maximum environment variable length; [2,048](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906469) or [32,768](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686206%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) bytes depending on the source), not all software will be able to read and handle it correctly if it is too long.

Comment: Is reboot really required here ? How does setx do it ? Setx does not require reboot.

Comment: Yes, a reboot is required. `setx` edits the registry as I indicated, then broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message. This tells all top-level windows that a system setting has changed (in this case an environment variable). Without that, Explorer and programs you opened with it will not know about the change. You *could* broadcast the message yourself manually (I wrote a program to do just that, and a batch file to replace `SETX` that makes a registry edit followed by the broadcast), but just like `setx` and the System Properties envvar dialog, it has side-effects that make rebooting preferable.

Comment: Can you share your program with me ? I will be very useful.

Comment: I suppose, but like I said, it won’t help. It has the same effects that `setx` and the Env-Var dialog do. It notifies the system that the vars. have changed, but they don’t actually take effect until you restart them. In other words, you have to exit and re-run every program that you want to know about the change. Is there a reason you can’t reboot? Can the longer path wait until you can?

Comment: Oh and editing an env.var. actually causes problems if you don’t reboot because any environment variables that contain other variables will stop being expanded. For example, I just broadcast it and now [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GUOda.png) is my path and I get an error because the path is now “broken”/empty. None of the vars will expand properly again until I reboot. Unfortunately this is “normal”. `:-|`

Comment: I found a [small PowerShell script](http://poshcode.org/2049) that will broadcast the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message.

Comment: You can use the above registry method via the REG add command and then use SETX to set some other variable to itself (ie: SETX /M USERNAME %USERNAME%).  This will cause the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to be set and give your the ability to set the path from a batch file.

Comment: What about the [dialog box](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) that allows you to set `%PATH%`? Editing the registry seems a bit extreme.

Comment: For current user, use HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment

Comment: @JustinDearing the link is broken, may you update it?

Comment: @EkremDİNÇEL, it's [archived in the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170516120430/http://poshcode.org/2049).

Comment: No reboot required. I did this and restarting the command prompt window, all variables are initialized. No reboot.

Comment: @BosnianCoder, it depends on how you start the command-prompt. If you start it from Explorer, then it will/*should* have the new data. But if you run it from another program like if you have Task Manager running in the tray, or in my case, I use AutoHotkey to open a command prompt using a hotkey, then it won't work until you re-run that program (for some reason, either broadcasting `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` isn't working, or setx just doesn't do it right ). Either way, saying to reboot is a blanket step to cover all scenarios.

Comment: @Synetech you need to just relaunch AutoHotkey. Just restart it, and CMD called by it will see the new PATH.

Comment: @Synetech I use custom C++ low level keyboard hook launcher for regedit (short press) and CMD (long press) that launches them with a press of just one OEM button, that cannot be bind by any other hotkey managers. And my program have no windows, so, same as AutoHotkey, it just can't receive this `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` in any way. So you don't need to restart PC, just restart the program that spawns CMDs.

Comment: I allocated probably too much effort to [created a tool](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/shellsymlnk) that solves this problem decisively. Details are in the readme.

Answer (score 37):

if you are using windows vista or higher, you can make a `symbolic link` to the folder. for example:

```
mklink /d C:\pf "C:\Program Files"
mklink /d C:\pf86 "C:\Program Files (x86)"
```

would make a link so `c:\pf` would be your program files folder. I shaved off 300 characters from my path by using this trick.

(I know it's not related to setx but it is useful for people which are searching overcomming on 1024 char limit)

Comment: Useful when you are an administrator. For the rest of us: `You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation`. In a pinch,`subst` can do something similar.

Comment: Think about it, it's not the most optimal solution. Even if you symblink `Windows` and `system32` folders you will eventually run out of 1024 char limit. What is much smarter is to add some folder like `C:\slnk` in the PATH variable and then create symbolic links to all the programs/files you want to launch from path in that folder! This way, you will never, ever run out of PATH, even after adding thousands of programs! @AmitNaidu you can also do this with hard links instead of symbolic links, hard links does not require administrative privileges!

Comment: Also, symbolic links in path variable might make some programs exert undefined behaviour, I suspect.

Comment: I allocated probably too much effort to [created a tool](https://github.com/ScienceDiscoverer/shellsymlnk) that solves this problem decisively. Details are in the readme.

Answer (score 28):

You could use a PowerShell script similar to the following:

```
$newPath = 'F:\common tools\git\bin;F:\common tools\python\app;F:\common tools\python\app\scripts;F:\common tools\ruby\bin;F:\masm32\bin;F:\Borland\BCC55\Bin'
$oldPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine');
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', "$newPath;$oldPath",'Machine');
```

The [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx) API call will broadcast [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx) so you do not need to reboot.

Comment: Don't you also need the following line: [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path', "$newPath",'Machine');

Comment: In the 3rd line, I'm not sure what benefit the extra dollar signs and parentheses bring. Couldn't you just say `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path', "$newPath;$oldPath",'Machine')` ?

Comment: @twasbrillig I'm just careful when I'm including a variable in a string. in this case its unecessary.

Comment: You can call this from an Administrator Command Prompt: `@"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path',\"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG;$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('path','Machine'))\",'Machine');"`

Answer (score 7):

This open-source SetEnv command-line tool is good to edit the PATH and other environment variables without limitations. It uses a dynamic buffer so no static limitations like 1024.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12153/SetEnv

The choice of a % as a prefix to append to a variable could have been better though, as makes the syntax difficult sometimes if used with other batch local variables...

Comment: *> SetEnv tool is good to edit the PATH and other environment variables without limitations*   Indeed. In fact, I had personally worked with Darka on that page to help make SetEnv even better so that it can fully support expanding/sub-variables (the Dynamic Variable Expansion section), which actually helps to *reduce* the length of the raw path.

Answer (score 4):

A far superior tool than setx for path manipulation is [pathed.exe](http://www.p-nand-q.com/download/gtools/pathed.html). Unfortunately, it's limited to editing the path.

In addition to a superior user experience than setx, you don't have a 1024 character limit. Unlike direct registry manipulation, this application uses the [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable.aspx) API call which will broadcast [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: There's a list of other tools (including pathed.exe) at superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7

Answer (score 3):

You can put this line in your BAT:

```
setx path "%%path%%;c:\drive\fr;c:\drive\installs\7z"
```

See the double `%%`.

(Reference:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/75634)

Comment: Link is now broken

Comment: WARNING! This possibly will break things, it will write `%path%;c:\...[snip]...\7z` to the user `path` variable, dropping anything else you had there.

Comment: The PATH environment variable used by programs is a combination of the machine and local PATH variables. In addition to destroying the current data in the local path I don't think this does anything. Having `%path%` in the local path environment variable should have no effect.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite way is to change the folder names in the PATH variables to use the 8.3 names.  [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20362922/528061) has an awesome script (run from a .bat file) that will generate the "minified" version of the entire PATH variable, which you can then paste into the Edit Variable dialog(s).  Only caveat is that you will need to split out the SYSTEM and USER parts.  As the script goes through and figures out the minified version for each folder, it discards and alerts you of any invalid/non-existent paths.  Nice little clean up bonus.

Comment: Be careful if you have used `fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 1`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton good point but wouldn't that be "handled" by the fact that the script doesn't "generate" the 8.3 name, it just reports the 8.3 name that the file system assigned? So if a folder did not have an 8.3 name, the script would not propose a substitute. However, using `fsutil 8dot3name strip` AFTER using the script would definitely cause problems for affected folders.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a spare drive or system to check it on. However, having used some `fsutil 8dot3name strip` earlier today and considering that (a) it checks the registry first and (b) the path is stored in the registry, my earlier concern may be unwarranted, as long as the user does not use the `/f` (force) option.

Comment: This solution is not very good, as no matter how much you shorten PATH paths, you will eventually run out of 1024 characters.

Comment: And you are entitled to that opinion.  I never said this was the BEST way to do it, just that it is MY favorite way (and I have never had problems with it).  If you use this method and still hit the 1024 limit you may want to rethink everything installed on your machine and/or any paths you may have added manually.  Some of the other ways here are much more "invasive" and one even mentions that some software may not work with it.  That is what is so awesome with having choices, you can choose which one suits your fancy.

Answer (score 1):

A new tool is born, it works very well, have unique features and solve all setx problems: [regenv](https://github.com/lunakid/regenv)

- it works in xp+.
- it is better than setx ,pathed, pathman, setenv
- it is a fork of the old nice setenv tool

```vb
set "var=D:\Bin"

REM ::::: override a system var:
regenv.exe set -nS c "%var%"

REM ::::: append to a system var
regenv.exe set -nS -sa c "%var%"

REM ::::: preppend to a system var
regenv.exe set -nS -sp c "%var%"

REM ::::: create a variable that contains an unexpanded variable
regenv.exe set -nS -sp c "%%var%%"

REM ::::: edit PATH: if you edit PATH it is good to use -x , because -x will convert the reg type from REG_SZ to REG_EXPAND_SZ, because some tools may create a REG_SZ while the default reg type for PATH is/should be REG_EXPAND_SZ
regenv.exe set -nS -sp -x PATH "%var%"
```

NB: if var contain a backslash at the end, use [double backlash](https://github.com/lunakid/regenv/issues/1):

```vb
regenv.exe set -nS c "D:\Bin\\"
REM gaves D:\Bin\
```

or delete the last backslash:

```vb
set "var=D:\Bin\"
REM -- Great example from Strawberry Perl's portable shell launcher:  this deletes the final backslash \.
if #%var:~-1%# == #\# set var=%var:~0,-1%
regenv.exe set -nS c "%var%"
:: gaves D:\Bin
```

it can even create Volatile variables (HKCU\Volatile Environment).

it is really a nice work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is the next (with powershell)
With this way also you avoid the litmit of 1024 character.

You can see the code on: https://gist.github.com/drazul/b92f780689bd89a0d2a7

```
#------------ Add path to system variable -------------------------------------

$path2add = ';C:\path;'
$systemPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'machine');

If (!$systemPath.contains($path2add)) {
    $systemPath += $path2add
    $systemPath = $systemPath -join ';'
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $systemPath, 'Machine');
    write-host "Added to path!"
    write-host $systemPath
}

#------------ Delete path from system variable --------------------------------

$path2delete = 'C:\path;'
$systemPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'machine');

$systemPath = $systemPath.replace($path2delete, '')
$systemPath = $systemPath -join ';'

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $systemPath, 'Machine');

write-host "Deleted from path!"
write-host $systemPath

#------------ Clean system variable -------------------------------------------

$systemPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'machine');

while ($systemPath.contains(';;')) {
    $systemPath = $systemPath.replace(';;', ';')
}

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $systemPath, 'Machine');

write-host "Cleaned path!"
write-host $systemPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little ready-to-use packing of the Powershell version . Save this as a `.cmd` or `.bat`, UTF-8 or ASCII text file . Remember to restart programs that were running during the change .

```
@echo off
set br=^


rem br;
pushd "%~dp0"       &rem Working/{temp files} Directory . pat>->paf ;
setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion


rem # Required :
rem Windows Powershell v1.0 by Microsoft .
rem # ;


echo Make sure to run this as Administrator .!br!
pause
echo(
set v=

set /p v=Enter the items to add . Separate by, and end the list with ";" . Do not use quotes .!br!!br!&     rem #optional

rem set v=C:\Windows\WinSxS;!v!     &rem MSBuild ; #optional

"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path',\"%v%$([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path','Machine'))\",'Machine');"      &rem Windows Powershell by Microsoft ;


:sc_n
rem endlocal
rem popd
pause
rem exit /b
```

Answer (score -2):

if it is not required to keep system PATH and user PATH separate:

```
::setx /m truncate variable length to 1024 REG ADD 
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v PATH /t REG_SZ /f /d "%PATH%"
::empty local path, use system wide only, else it will enlarge with every setx /m
setx PATH ""
::setx is dummy but propagate system wide variables with it
setx /m A A
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are suggesting here?

Comment: It is just a ready to use command to workaround setx 1024 character limit. Example is shown directly on PATH variable.
Although the previous answers are helpful they lack a final solution.

Comment: System path and user path are separate for a reason. This combines them and puts everything in the system path. That is a major change to the environment behavior and is not expected by a user who is just looking to add something to their user path variable.