# how do i install ffmpeg-4.1.3.tar on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, amr

I have downloaded the FFMPEG file and now have no idea what to do with it now it is in the downloads folder.
I need it so I can convert amr to MP3 files
Help please.

Comment: Why did you download a unix tar for Windows? Go back & get the Windows zip

Comment: [Builds - Zeranoe FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

Answer (score 1):

#### Installing FFmpeg in Windows

> 1. Download a static build from [here](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/).
> 2. Use 7-Zip to unpack it in the folder of your choice.
> 3. [Open a command prompt with administrator's rights](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Just-Enough-Command-Line-for-Installing).
>
>    NOTE: Use `CMD.exe`, do not use Powershell! The syntax for accessing
>      environment variables is different from the command shown in Step 4 -
>      running it in Powershell will overwrite your System PATH with a bad
>      value.
> 4. Run the command (see note below; in Win7 and Win10, you might want to use the Environmental Variables area of the Windows Control
>      Panel to update PATH):
>
>    ```
>    setx /M PATH "path\to\ffmpeg\bin;%PATH%"
>    ```
>
>    Do not run `setx` if you have more than 1024 characters in your
>      system `PATH` variable.
>
>    See [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx) that discusses alternatives. Be sure
>      to alter the command so that path\to reflects the folder path from
>      your root to `ffmpeg\bin`.
>
> [Here is another explanation with pictures](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows).

Source [Installing FFmpeg · adaptlearning/adapt_authoring Wiki · GitHub](https://github.com/adaptlearning/adapt_authoring/wiki/Installing-FFmpeg)