# overcoming the WARNING: The length of the extracted value is truncated to 1024 characters

Tags: environment-variables

I have read this solution but they all fall into the case of the path which is not my case.

[Overcoming the 1024 character limit with setx](https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx)
Basically I created and want to use my environment variable, let's call it MY_VAR which will be quite a long string (for example a credential)
When defining this over the web ui in windows it works just fine.
But I would like to automate this and do this from the command line.
I was exploring the setx and even by using a file for example:

```
setx MY_VAR /f my_file.txt /a 0,1

WARNING: The length of the extracted value is truncated to 1024 characters.

Extracted value: .... value is correctly displayed.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

I still get said warning even if the extracted value is correct but when I access the variable over "set" I still see it truncated to the 1024 chars.

Is there a way to go around this? Because I can do it from the UI for sure there must be a way to do this from the command line no?

Thanks for any feedback, I know that the question is pretty similar to the one I just linked but honestly all the solutions I see there are very focused on the path but that is not my problem I really just want to define a value that is longer than 1024.
I did not explore the part about the registry because honestly I don't know how that works.

Comment: I occasionally store the shorter of two key pairs in a user environment variable, then the longer key in a file stored in my private user profile area (where auditing is enabled).  As a work-around, I might suggest changing your MY_VAR to point to the file path location containing your larger data set; as you may get unexpected results relying on environment data larger than 1024 chars, especially with legacy 32-bit apps.

Comment: this is something we want to do for our developers because in our normal setup the keys are stored in secrets and vaults but I can't access the vault from the dev setup so we just have dummy credentials defined locally but I think I'm not aware of how to do them to point to the file. can you explain that a bit better or just point me to one example?

Comment: Essentially, most developers know how to read the value of an environment variable, and to get the contents of a file.  Move the larger [encoded/encrypted] data sets to files (for auditing), then either reference those files via environment variables, or pass the path as arguments to code.  If you ever need to decode/decrypt anything in those files (and don't need to audit access), keep shorter data sets in environment variables -- in essence, avoid keeping the two secrets together.

Comment: You cannot use a system variable that is longer than 1024 which is exactly what you are doing by using SETX. You will have to go to your developers and ask for a better solution then using system variables

Comment: You could split the value into 2 or more variables.  However, you would have to output them 1 at a time as you can't combine variables over said length.