# Where i can find apps that existed in "start" command on cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe

i wanna get the path of the folder so that i can see or add apps to start them from start command in cmd.

[Screenshot from the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoqiD.jpg)

Comment: What you want it to add a new path to your PATH variable, so you can run programs from CMD, check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7

Comment: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](//superuser.com/q/284342)

Answer (score 1):

Right-click items in your start menu, and select properties.
You will find the path to the executables.