# Add a new path to PATH but end up with editing the last existing path in PATH

Tags: windows-10, path, environment-variables

In Windows 10, when i open the window for editing PATH variable, and would like to add a new path to PATH, I click "New" and then click "Browse..." to select the directory whose pathname I want to add to PATH. But it ends up editing the last existing path in PATH. Do I miss something? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?  It seems straight forward: [Is there a convenient way to edit PATH in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7)

Comment: Windows 10 has a different user interface for changing the value of PATH.

Comment: I am aware of that fact.  There is an appliciable answer.  I would still like clarification from you though.