# Running a .bat file as a command on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I have the following in `build-site.bat`:

```
set JEKYLL_ENV=production 
bundle exec jekyll build
```

I'd like to have the `bat` file residing in my documents area under a folder say `scripts`. I'd then like to be able to `cd` into a Github repo, and type `build-site` and have the bat run.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your scripts directory the PATH of your environment. Afterwards stuff that's within your PATH will be available the way you want.

As for how to change the PATH have a look at:

- [Is there a convenient way to edit PATH in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7) on Super User
- [How can I modify a user’s PATH environment variable without logging out?](https://serverfault.com/questions/33681/how-can-i-modify-a-user-s-path-environment-variable-without-logging-out) on Server Fault

There are plenty more resources available.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much! I will accept your answer when I can :D