# PATH environment variable is represented by a single row in explorer GUI

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

In Explorer, when trying to edit the `PATH` environment variable on Windows 10 via `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System` » Advanced » Environment Variables, `PATH` is represented by a single row:

- ```
   %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;%HADOOP_HOME%;
  ```

  Screenshot:[image: Screenshot1]

Usually, the GUI of the variable, represented by multiple rows, is shown:

- [How to Edit Your System PATH for Easy Command Line Access in Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/)
- [How to Add to Windows PATH Environment Variable](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) 
   [image: Screenshot2]

How do I access the GUI multi-row table for the `PATH` environment variable as shown above?

Comment: Have you tried Open Control Panel » System » Advanced » Environment Variables?

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what happened (I clarify my question)

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen the multi-line one before.

Comment: @gronostaj The multi-line GUI window was added in Windows 10, though not sure in what bi-annual update _(I noticed in a year or so ago)_.

Comment: @user3563894 An FYI about the System `PATH`: the OS entries should be first, with any additions added to the bottom of `PATH` in the GUI or at the end of `PATH` if as a single line _(the User `PATH` can have entries anywhere)_. It's likely there's a Registry setting for showing the `PATH` GUI, however you may as well rule out system file corruption by executing the following in an Admin terminal, _in the order listed_: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` → `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`  → Reboot → `SFC /ScanNow` → Reboot → Test if issue still exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Is there a convenient way to edit PATH in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/297947/is-there-a-convenient-way-to-edit-path-in-windows-7/297950#297950)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first element of the list must **not** be the *percent sign character* (used as variable expansion character on MsDOS/Windows) for the graphical editor to show the variable as a multi-line list **unless** the variable to expand is `%SYSTEMROOT%`.

This is a "bug" in `C:\Windows\System32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe` that's been present since the introduction of the multi-line editor in Windows 10 build 10586 (November 2015 update). It looks like this "bug" is an oversight by Microsoft since `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32` and `%SYSTEMROOT%` (in that order) should **always** be present in your Path environment variable anyway.

You can simply prepend those two elements to the Path environment variable in order to solve this problem.
For example:

```
 %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;%HADOOP_HOME%;
```

Becomes:

```
 %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;%HADOOP_HOME%;
```

Comment: Saved me a lot of time! Thanks.

Comment: As of W10 22H2 (3448), this bug has been fixed.