# How to display each location of Windows PATH on a separate line using the GUI

Tags: windows, windows-10, environment-variables, path

I don't know what changed about my settings, but recently the dialog box under Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables -> System Variables -> select Path -> Edit is not showing each location on a separate line like **it used to be**. My machine runs on Windows 10.

I would like to go from

https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/screenshot.4-2-650x187.png

to this

https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/2016-03-24_11h02_18.png

Comment: Is your computer domain joined? What version of Windows 10 are you using? Have you installed all windows updates?

Comment: I have the same, and it seemed that my path was literally just one row and as such it did not go into multi edit. Once I edited and typed ;test at the end, it went back to multiline, but now I can't seem to get the first path back, so copy what it was before doing this in case you have to get back to what it was before.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow these steps, I get to the expected dialog

1. Click Start
2. Type `environment variables`
3. Select [image]
4. Select `Environment Variables` from the `System Properties` dialog
5. Find `Path` in the `System Variables` section [image]
6. Click `Edit...` with `Path` highlighted in the table of System Variables
   This results in the below
   [image]

An alternative solution is to run `$env:Path -split ';'` in PowerShell, which will return a list of environment Path variables.

Comment: It doesn't do this on my end. My computer is domain joined and as such I have extra buttons about Active Directory. I have a feeling this has something to do with it.

Comment: My machine is on a domain, but I am a local admin. It could be priveledges related...

Comment: I'm local admin on my end too. So we can rule that out then. Could also be a windows update that changes this... dunno. I get what you see in the first link of OP with 2 buttons extra: `Search in Active Directory...` and `Search in file...`

Comment: I've added an alternative, which is a PowerShell command.

Comment: Which version of Windows 10 are you using? Win10 x64 v20H2 or any other? I am running Win10 x64 v1909

Comment: v1909 build 18363.1440

Comment: v1909 build 18363.1316 here. Interesting. I see the same window on my server, Windows Server 2016. Also one line. Still think it has something to do with being domain joined.

Answer (score 2):

There are two known Windows bugs that prevent the multi-line display of the
PATH:

1. If the first character of the PATH is `%`, except when this is
   `%SYSTEMROOT%` ([link](https://superuser.com/a/1594989/8672))
2. If the PATH is malformed, for example if the separator is not `;`

If these conditions do not apply to your problem, then you might have
a Windows 10 corruption that you should check using
[SFC and DISM](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

For desperate cases, an alternative software is the free
[System Path Commander](https://download.cnet.com/System-Path-Commander/3000-2094_4-10438074.html).
Although an old product, I tested and it still works on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Running C:\WINDOWS\system32\SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe on my end gives me the one liner, not the multi-edit tool. So the way you access it does not seem to matter. Either on your system it has the multi-line or the single-line edit window.

Comment: @LPChip: Which Windows version?

Comment: I run Windows 10 x64 Professional 1909 build 18363.1316. Spikey Richy runs the same, only a build newer, and he has the multiple rows view. So build is not a factor it seems.

Comment: @LPChip: Is the first character of your PATH variable the `%`? If yes, rearrange so it's not the first and try again.

Comment: Its not, but you made me look closely to my path and I discovered its a weird path, so I edited it, added a ; test to it and now its multiline

Comment: Ah ha, so it's caused by malformed PATH. I'll add it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you and I didn't realize it until this question. I did some investigating and it turns out that the following is true:

If your Path environmental variable actually only contains one path, it is showing the single-line edit control. If it contains a `;` which means there are multiple parameters, then it treats it as multi-line and the dialogue box changes to what you expect to see.

For me to get the multi-line box, all I have to do is append a `;` at the end. If your current path contains invalid characters, the current path will be hidden and only one empty line is shown instead. The control does give a button called <kbd>Edit Text</kbd> to restore it back to a single line edit control, so you can get back to what it was.